# Signify that a question is migrated in the app, or just redirect

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, android-app

I recently saw [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18002/3808) on the "newest" tab of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com. So, I tried to downvote and vote to delete, and I got the message "this question is locked."

Huh??? I had no idea why it would be locked, so I tried to view it on the main site, when I was promptly redirected to code golf meta.

Could there be a migrated banner, like the close banner? Or could we just be redirected to the place it was migrated to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Was the closed banner not at the bottom of the question when you looked at it? Here's what it looks like to me, this might've been a "the question was *right* migrated after you clicked to view it" situation.</s>

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEaMYl.png

As of version 0.1.85 coming out around midnight UTC the app has a banner similar to the one for closed questions which indicates that a migrated post has been migrated and you can tap it to view the migrated version. I tried doing auto-redirecting but it was very confusing since the only thing that shows you that you're on a different site is the titlebar (confusing enough that I thought it didn't work until I read more carefully!)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yes, the closed banner was there, but I had no idea that it was migrated. I tried to vote on it, and got "this question is locked," which was very confusing.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I'll see what I can do with regards to doing the redirect instead of dealing with the special case of "closed and locked and migrated" questions.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow answer updated, actually fixed now :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for working so hard :-D